Flutter error : Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1, Please how to solve it in Vscode
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\flutter\test_drive> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK
built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...  Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...          at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1581)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...          at java.base/java.util.zip.Zi        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...          at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...          at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48) 
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...          at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...          at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1 189ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed
with exit code 1
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\flutter\test_drive>
 *  History restored 

PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\flutter\test_drive> 
 *  History restored 

PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\flutter\test_drive> 
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)        
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)        
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)        
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)     
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)     
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2 229ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
exit code 1

I'm a beginner in flutter, need help.

Could you please try running flutter doctor --verbose command and check whether everything works fine or not? Also could you please verify that the internet is good?

Have you tried this solution link
